# Angular File Upload Queue

Tags: angularjs, file-upload

I'm using this  [Angular File Upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload) library for my uploading process.

It uploads perfectly okay using the same setup that is listed on that repo.

However, I have to have the files upload in a queue (1 file after another) as opposed to all the files uploading at the same time.

[Example](http://nervgh.github.io/pages/angular-file-upload/examples/simple/).

The example is using a fork repo and the requirement is that I use the one I listed.

Other options such as pause/cancel will also be needed.

Current setup:

```
Controller:

 $scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
  for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
  //loop through files and put in an array
   }
    //execute upload function
    $scope.start(files);
  }
 }
};

$scope.start = function(index) {
  $upload.upload({
   //upload clode
  }).progress(function(evt) {
   //Progress calculation
  }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    //Success return
  }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data);
  });
};
```

Comment: You can use recursive function and the recursive function should call once you met all conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, basically it just sends one file at a time until done. You could use $timeout if you would prefer a delay between sending each file:

```
$scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
    $scope.uploadList = $files;
    $scope.uploadIndex = 0;
    $scope.start(uploadIndex)
};

$scope.start = function() {
  $upload.upload({
   //upload code, send file
   // Send file $scope.uploadList[$scope.uploadIndex];
  }).progress(function(evt) {
   //Progress calculation
  }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    //Success return
    $scope.uploadIndex++;
    // Send the next file by calling ourselves
    if (uploadIndex < uploadList.length)
        $scope.start();   // Send the next one now - could be deferred a little by using $timeout
  }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log(data);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For now you should manage your queue yourself. You can start new uploads on finally of the previous uploads.